# loki - missing wingpanel after messing with dconf

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, dconf

I recently installed elementary OS on my Desktop computer, and after customizing a little bit with dconf settings my wingpanel (topbar) dissapeared. Maximizing an application doesn't cover the space where it's supposed to be.

Using `killall wingpanel` doesn't do anything, maximizing windows act as if it's gone and recover the original size as if it's back, but no top bar appears.

Tried to purge the package `wingpanel` and reinstalling it again but it had no effect.

What could be the cause of this?

Any help would be appreciated and it would save me from reinstalling the whole system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could download dconf tools (`sudo apt install dconf-tools`), search for the values you remember changing and pressing the restore to default button. This will change the values back to their default values, hopefully fixing your issues.

The value you've changed is probably located somewhere in the `Pantheon` namespace.